# Пересылка сообщения и после этого вывод inline кнопки (telebot)

Tags: python, telebot, inline

Суть такая: Бот начинает оформлять заявку. Просит ввести имя, пересылает это сообщение в чат с админами, после принятого сообщения просит написать номер телефона и пересылает это сообщение в тот-же чат. Почему то не хочет реагировать кнопка после нажатия на нее

```
    if call.data == 'salebutton':
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def text(message):
    admin_id = -1001844045667
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        bot.send_message(chat_id,'Пришлите, что хотите отправить')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message,send_z)
def send_z(message):
    first_name = message.chat.first_name
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user_name = message.chat.username
    z = message.text
    admin_id = -1001844045667
    app_text = []
    app_name = []
    app_username = []
    app_name.append(first_name)
    app_username.append(user_name)
    app_text.append(z)
    bot.send_message(admin_id, f"Поступила заявка от {app_name}!\n"
                                f"Его username = {app_username}\n"
                                f"Его текст:\n"
                                f"{app_text}")
    app_name.clear()
    app_username.clear()
    app_text.clear()
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "Заявка отправлена ")
```

Comment: Что за одинокое `if call.data == 'salebutton':`?

Comment: это "вырезка из кода"))

Answer (score 0):

Если еще не нашел решение - исправь на:

```
f"Поступила заявка от {app_name[0]}!\n"
f"Его username = @{app_username[0]}\n"
f"Его текст:\n"
f"{app_text[0]}")
```